# How to create a dynamic table from another table's data in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table "Car" where I have two columns Cname and Ccolor. I would like this table or a new table which contains a list of cars with a common color, and to have this bind dynamically.

**What I have:**

```
+---------+--------+
|  Cname  | Ccolor |
+---------+--------+
| Ferrari | Red    |
| Maruti  | Red    |
| Phantom | Red    |
| Duster  | Black  |
| Beetle  | Black  |
| Hummer  | White  |
| Skoda   | White  |
| Pajero  | White  |
+---------+--------+
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
+---------+--------+-----------------+
|  Cname  | Ccolor | CommonColorCar  |
+---------+--------+-----------------+
| Ferrari | Red    | Maruti Phantom  |
| Maruti  | Red    | Ferrari Pahntom |
| Phantom | Red    | Ferrari Maruti  |
| Duster  | Black  | Beetle          |
| Beetle  | Black  | Duster          |
| Hummer  | White  | Skoda Pajero    |
| Skoda   | White  | Hummer Pajero   |
| Pajero  | White  | Hummer Skoda    |
+---------+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself so far? Did you do any research before posting your question? Are there any problems you run up against?

Comment: Yes I tried by myself but not able to get the result. I am also not an expert in sql.

Comment: If you tried yourself, please post your SQL statements (and/or other accompanying code you have) and explain which errors you got or at which part your run aground. Showing effort in trying to solve you own problem will motivate the SO community into getting you onto the right track.

Comment: SELECT Cname
Ccolor
FROM car
GROUP BY Ccolor
HAVING ( COUNT(Ccolor) > 1 )

Comment: I tried this but I am only getting the last value of same color...

Comment: My mistake - by posting I meant: update you current question so all the relevant information is in one place (not scattered throughout the comments).

Comment: You can get Maruti Ferrari... sequence is not an issue... In case of Duster only Beetle is having the same color of Duster.

Comment: In third column only those car should have which match with the color of Cname... For e.g. in 1st row.. Ferrari is having Red color so in the CommonColorcar column I want only those car which are having Only "Red" Color.

Comment: 'Skoda Hummer' is having white color so they should be within the row which is having white color. And that is Pajero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think why you might want to concatenate this result, but anyway...

```
SELECT x.* 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.name) 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.color = x.color 
   AND y.name <> x.name 
 GROUP  
    BY x.name
     , x.color;
```

Comment: Mohammad, I completely agree with Strawberry: This data can be computed at any given time (when you *need* the info). Furthermore, if values in your database change along the way, your `CommonColorCar` column will go out of sync, so you will have to foresee some triggers inside your database to keep this column sane (more reason *not* to have this column in the first place). Strawberry...did you just delete all you comments on OP`s question?

Comment: @strawberry : can you tell me what is <> here ??

Comment: LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.color = x.color 
   AND y.name <> x.name 
 GROUP  
    BY x.name
     , x.color;   what this part is performing in this code ??

Comment: @mohammadshahbazKhan any basic introduction to mysql would answer all of these questions

Comment: @Timusan He can delete them